# Font size of inline code-listings too small

Tags: formatting, listings, code, inline

I'm using the listings package and am satisfied with how my code listings look. The font in my inline-listings however is too small compared to the rest of the text. **How can I only increase the font size of inline-listings?**

this:

```
There also \lstinline{Send} and \lstinline$Receive$ classes to transfer data
```

becomes this:

[image]

This is my common style:

```
% common styles
\lstdefinestyle{common} {
  tabsize=2,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1, 
  inputencoding=latin1, 
  lineskip=-1pt,
  rulecolor=,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  columns=flexible,
  upquote=true,
  aboveskip={1.3\baselineskip},
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false,
  prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  escapechar=@,
  frame=single,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{1.0,0,0},
  keywordstyle=[1]\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color[rgb]{0.5,0.0,0.0},
  keywordstyle=[3]\color[rgb]{0.127,0.427,0.514},
  keywordstyle=[4]\color[rgb]{0.4,0.4,0.4},
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.266,0.537,0.553},
  stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.769,0.114,0.145},
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete document we can compile to reproduce the problem. How should we know what options you pass the class or what font packages you use?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161549/scaling-inline-code-to-the-current-font-size

Answer (score 2):

The inline verbatim is small because you specify it that way! Change the line

```
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
```

to

```
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
```

or whatever and you'll be fine.

Comment: the question is about changing style in _inline_ snippets, while your proposal would change style also in whole-paragraph snippets.